# convert inputs to integer and print asteriks

Tags: javascript

**strong text**Hi i have to convert the input in the text field to integer and display number of asterisk but cant get it done...what should i do.

```
  <body>
    <button onclick="go()">Click Me!!!</button>
    <input id="input" ></input>
    <p id="output">Change Me</p>
  </body>

js file
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

function go(){

var in = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value,10);
var out = document.getElementById('output');

  if(in>=1 && in<=10)
  {

  for (i<in;i++)
    {
       for (j<i ;j++)
        {
          out.innerHTML = "*";
        }
        console.console.log("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reword your question please?

Comment: I guess you meant `out.innerHTML += "*"`

Comment: So I have to take an input i.e of type string and convert in to an integer value and then in the paragraph tag print the number of * instead of change me

Comment: i changed it but its still not working

Comment: if input value is 3 you want  " *** " ? Not even sure why you have a double loop

Comment: no it should have one asterick in line 1, 2 in line 2 and 3 in line 3 like a pyramid

Comment: You have several coding mistakes, and in is a reserved word so you shouldn´t name a variable that way. I believe this is what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/vwz4go9n/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To get the best out of this site, you should take a minute to read the how-to-ask page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure your question meets the guidelines.